# Nginx reverse proxy with react service - cannot load styles

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have docker swarm app with multiple services and have problems with one service which is a react app. My config looks like this:

```
   location /web/ {
     include /etc/nginx/proxy-options/proxy.conf;
     set $webapp webapp;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
     proxy_pass http://$webapp$uri$is_args$args;
     sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/web/';
     sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/web/';
     sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/web/';
     sub_filter_once off;
  }

  location /app-info/ {
     include /etc/nginx/proxy-options/proxy.conf;
     proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
     proxy_redirect off;
     set $webapp webapp;
     proxy_pass http://$webapp$uri/$is_args$args;
     sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/web/';
     sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/web/';
     sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/web/';
     sub_filter_once off;
  }
```

Webapp is the react application hosted in docker also served with nginx. One of it's pages is webapp/app-info.
When setup through reverse proxy when I try to access anything on webapp I just get white screen and in the console I can see these errors. At this moment I'm out of ideas what I'm doing wrong.

> Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/web/static/css/main.23d98db9.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Now what I'm trying to achieve (beside just making /web work) is making only /app-info/ accessible from outside. I would like to (temporary) block any access to webapp, beside the requests to /app-info. Is that possible?

Edit: Forgot to mention - everything works perfectly fine with

```
 location / {
     include /etc/nginx/proxy-options/proxy.conf;
     set $webapp webapp;
     proxy_pass http://$webapp$uri$is_args$args;
     proxy_redirect http://$webapp/ $scheme://$http_host/;
  }
```

Comment: you're missing `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`

Comment: After adding it nothing changed